# How can I log some records from a web service(POST) in a log file in Java?

Tags: java, logging

I want to create a log file and save information given by a web service POST.

The object logger created like this:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(B2BUnitController.class.getName());
```

I don't know how to proceed to make the log file and save the information.

Comment: What framework / library are you using?

Comment: Since you had already using log4j classes mentioned above, you need to create log4j.properties file in your src/main/resources folder. Syntax for log4j.properties file is easily available. Apart from this, above class post method you need to use logger.info methods for writing into file. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Since your a using log4j. add the following to your project property files

```
logging.path=/data/logs
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.file=/data/logs/test.log
logging.pattern.console="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -----|  %msg%n"
logging.pattern.file="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} ----|  %msg%n"
```

basically the above code will create folder `data/logs` then inside that folder it will create your logs file with the name `test.log`.

Lastly log your information as below

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(B2BUnitController.class.getName());

logger.info("information received {}",objectWithInformationThatShouldGoInLogs);
```

Then you are done it will print log in your console as well as your file.

**To view your logs in Json format**.

add the following Gson dependency.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(B2BUnitController.class.getName());
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

logger.info("information received {}",gson.ToJson(objectWithInformationThatShouldGoInLogs));
```

You can read more information on logs on the following sites

[Introduction to SLF4J Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-with-log4j2-logback)

[working with SLF4J Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-with-slf4j)

[Gson Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide)

***NB yml property file**

```
logging:
  path: /data/logs/
  level:
   root: INFO
   org:
    springframework:
      security: INFO
  file:  /data/logs/test.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -----|  %msg%n"
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} ----|  %msg%n"
```

Comment: Another thing. I need to create those log files into a server folder, Can I add the path in logging.path in the project properties file?. Also the call to the web service(POST) will create new records in the same file or will create several files with the new records?  I need it to save the new records in the same log file.

Comment: that path ( `/data/logs` ) is created in the server where your application is running. all records will go into one file and these files are archived on a daily basis.

Comment: @ArkhamHdz did my solution work?.Kindly accept the answer so that we can help others